# 'Click' Sound on Applying Brake

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, noise

I have 2014 Honda Civic; couple of months ago, my car's brakes started making a weird 'Clicking' sound when I would apply brakes first time after my car is parked for say around 30 mins or so. Once made the sound, it won't make that sound again while my driving until the car is again parked for some decent amount of time.

I just got my Civic serviced for code B1 and I told dealer about this sound but on getting the delivery, they told they didn't do anything about that sound since they couldn't reproduce it. Funny part is, the moment I started pulling my car out of their parking, it made that sound :).

Does anyone know what could be causing this sound? I'm worried that brakes shouldn't fail while I'm with my family on a highway. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I reckon what you're hearing is the solenoid responsible for releasing the shift lock mechanism. Can you confirm that this is only heard when the car is in "P"?

Comment: Not in "P". When I start driving the car and the first time I apply brakes. 
Interestingly, there's no sound when I press brake pedal to move to R gear and even then to D gear. It gives sound only when I start driving forward and I apply brakes and only one time.

Comment: Does it make a clicking ( in the plural) or a single click? I've had older cars do single click noises like this, and it has been loose pads (as described by Arthur above). It isn't normally dangerous . Has anyone mucked with the brakes at all?

Comment: It makes a single Click. I'm not sure if anyone would have mucked the brakes as I've got the car serviced only once before this time and that too with the dealer (same).

Answer (score 1):

Next time you hear it click, come to a full stop, back up a bit, apply the brakes again to come to a stop, and try it forward again, listening for another click.  If it clicks again, I'd say either the pads are loose enough to slide a bit or possibly the caliper slide pins. I wouldn't worry about safety in either case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Arthur, I'll try this trick and let you know if it makes sound around the same spot. Also thanks for confirming that there's no safety concern as it was the main concern for me.

Answer (score 1):

Click sound on first stop could be floating calipers, which are probably operating as designed.

When you back up they move back into position and click when driven. Again, this is normal behaviour.

Comment: Ray - please don't use all caps in answers - it makes posts unreadable, and probably explains the down vote. I have edited to help.

Comment: My car (Acura TSX VTEC) has the same issue. It really annoys me now. The click sound only comes from right front wheel area when I press break hard. Soft breaking does not create the sound. I suspects if that is transmission solenoid problem, but not sure. It repeats if I stop and go in low speed (10mph).